# Linux C ext2fs_write_inode_full failing to write

Tags: c, linux, inode, ext2

after successfully reading the file inode with this:

```
retval = ext2fs_read_inode_full(current_fs, inode, inode_buf, EXT2_INODE_SIZE(current_fs->super));
if (retval) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read inode\n");
    free(fs);
    free(inode_buf);
    return retval;
}
```

(At this point I have verified the inode contains the correct data of the file in question)

I immediately attempt to write it back with this :

```
  retval = ext2fs_write_inode_full(current_fs, inode, inode_buf, EXT2_INODE_SIZE(current_fs->super));
  if (retval) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write inode %d\n", retval);
  }
```

(Of course it's my intention to change some date values in the inode before writing back)

But ext2fs_write_inode_full returns an error value 2133571349.

The program executes with root privileged!

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation fully? [libext2fs - Manual](http://www.giis.co.in/libext2fs.pdf) I ask, because tinkering with it, I don't even get the filesystem open. There is a project on [github - planetlabs / crtime](https://github.com/planetlabs/crtime/blob/master/crtime.c) that may be helpful. Hopefully others will have more specifics.

Comment: I used the code from crtime as my base.  I just added the call to ext2fs_read_inode_full.  Thanks for the pointer to the manual.

Comment: There's not a lot in the manual regarding ext2fs_read_inode_full

Comment: Correction to my previous comment I added the call to ext2fs_write_inode_full to crtime!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the way crtime was opening the FS with ext2fs_open.

I needed to pass the EXT2_FLAG_RW flag otherwise the open is by default read only.